# jQuery stopPropagation not working on table/mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

I have a submit form for login which looks like this:

```
handleLoginSubmit: function() {
    $('#login-form, .login-form').submit(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'loginURL',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (r) {
                if (r.redirect) {
                    window.location = r.redirect;
                } else {
                    //Wrong username or password
                }
            }
        });
    });
},
```

This works fine on my computer, and other computers for that matter. It also seems to work on my android phone. But I've tried it both on an iPad and an iPhone and neither works.

The problem is that when I submit the form I only get the json data printed out on the screen like this:

```
{"login":true,"redirect":"https://frontpageurl"}
```

But it is supposed to redirect to the front page url.

So when logging in, on an iPhone or an iPad, the redirect to front page does not work.

I first tried `e.preventDefault()` which seems to work fine in other similar parts of this project. Then I tried `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`. None of these seem to change anything.

Comment: Just as a side note, if you have a `form` with ID and class equal to `login-form`, this submit handler will be fired twice. Now without seeing any relevant MCVE, we can just guessing. Anyway, see Jai's answer, you probably don't want to stop propagation but prevent default behaviour

Answer (score 1):

> I doubt it that it is
>   *working on your computer and your android phone.*

As you are using `e.stopPropagation();` in the `submit` event which has a `$.ajax()` call and i have to say that has nothing to do with anything. When you do the submit your form get submitted.

If you are using ajax then first thing for you to follow is stop the form submission as you are using. You can do that with `event.preventDefault();`.  So, better to use it:

```
handleLoginSubmit: function() {
    $('#login-form, .login-form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // other code as is
},
```

---

About `e.stopPropagation();` is that it is used to stop the event to bubble up in the DOM tree to not to execute any event bound on parent elements. In your case it is not happening seems to me as form is getting submitted.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys!
At first I actually did use e.preventDefault() instead of e.stopPropagation() but I started to get this error before I changed it.
So even if I use e.preventDefault(), this form submit still doesn't work on an iPhone or an iPad. I still just get the json data printed out on the screen instead of being redirected to the front page.
Any ideas what might cause this behaviour?
Thanks again!